# Redux toolkit gives an error when state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
const initialState: TaskState = {
  tasks: [],
};

export const taskSlice = createSlice({
  name: "task",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTask: (state, action: PayloadAction<localTask>) => {
      state.tasks.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeTask: (state, action: PayloadAction<localTask>) => {
      state.tasks = state.tasks.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    updateTask: (state, action: PayloadAction<localTask>) => {
      state.tasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === action.payload.id) {
          task.title = action.payload.title;
          task.description = action.payload.description;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

This slice gives a warning when updateTask is dispatched:

`Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'task.tasks.3.description'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)]`

Can you please help me to get this issue fixed?
Thanks in advance.

I tried several ways including returning the new state object from the reducer function as well without any luck.

Comment: This warning occurs because you update the state directly. You need to create a copy of the state, edit it and then set the new state

Comment: Redux toolkit [uses immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers), which prevents state mutations within the reducers and allows you to actually use mutating syntax safely. This means the mutation is probably happening outside of your reducers in component code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a mutation of your Redux state outside of a reducer - probably somewhere in your component code.

That could look like

```
const task = useSelector(state => state.tasks.task[id])

// in an event handler
task.description = newValue // this line actually modifies your Redux store, because `task` is part of your store!
dispatch(updateTask(task))
```

instead you should do

```
const task = useSelector(state => state.tasks.task[id])

// in an event handler
dispatch(updateTask({ id: task.id, description: newValue }))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.
I now understand that when I selected the task it is a part of the store. 
I created an entirely new object and populated with the details and it did the trick!